# How to launch public AMI in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, realm, realm-mobile-platform

How can I find and launch a public AMI in Amazon EC2 console. In particular I want to launch the AMI provided by Realm for the Realm Object Server. Here is a screenshot of the name of this AMI.[image]

However, I cannot find this image in the  Choose an Amazon Machine Image window in Amazon. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

What steps should I take to launch a public AMI? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

It appears perfectly fine for me. Some tips:

- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the AMI ID to activate the search
- Make sure you are in the `us-east-1` region (as indicated in their [documentation](https://realm.io/kr/docs/get-started/installation/deployment/))
- I'd recommend using the `HVM` image, which is supported on all modern-generation EC2 instance types (eg `t2` and `m4`)

Answer (score 0):

After completing sign-up process.

Step 1: 
https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-east-1

[Note: Region is us-east-1. Change from top right corner.]

Step 2: Select `All services> Computing> EC2`

Step 3: In EC2 Dashboard in left pane, select `Images> AMIs`

Step 4: In search option select `Public images` and filter by `ami-f91bf083` for us-east-1.

Other AMI id are given in realm [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/deployment/#deploying-on-amazon-ec2)